# Div automatically takes it's max-width

Tags: html, css

The problem is no matter what is inside `chat_ttc` it will always be 300px.

Snippet:

```css
.chat_ttc {
  max-width: 300px;
  word-break: break-word;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  margin-left: 70px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  padding: 4px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  letter-spacing: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="froma_tc">
  <div class="chat_ttc">D</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yaa its because div is block element and it takes 100% of the width 
as you have given max-width as 300px width will be always 300px

if you want to take some valid width make div as inline-block

check this snippet

```css
.chat_ttc {
  max-width: 300px;

  display:inline-block;
  word-break: break-word;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  margin-left: 70px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  padding: 4px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  letter-spacing: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="froma_tc">
  <div class="chat_ttc">D</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks it did help!

Comment: You can mark it as correct. And yes: div is a block level element so if will take its max. Google inline vs block for more on this.